# Kentico - Multiple ##WHERE## macro in query text

Tags: kentico

I am receiving the following error when using multiple `##WHERE##` macros in a QueryDataSource

> Security Exception
>
> Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

I have a QueryDataSource with the following expression in the Where clause:

```
ranConStyle = '{%QueryString.cs#%}' and rgnme= {%QueryString.csnme.cs#%}
```

The query is:

```sql
Select * From CB_Gallery, CB_Products
WHERE 
x= xId AND 
y= 'Y' AND z= 'Y' AND 
(##WHERE##) 
ORDER BY z ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

The ##WHERE## and other query macros do have to contain valid SQL syntax and these macros are supposed to replace simple where conditions not to inject multiple parameters into the query.

You could replace whole where condition for the macro so the property would be like x= xId AND y= 'Y' AND z= 'Y' AND ranConStyle = '{%QueryString.cs#%}' AND rgnme= {%QueryString.csnme.cs#%}

But from my head I am not sure if it will pass the SQL syntax check.

These macros were never intended for complex use, but just to enable you to alter the queries from web parts without rewriting it, or to allow you to use same query on more places but this is limited by security. This is a security policy as were using these macros to inject all kinds of input to the webparts and even QueryStrings and other variables, that could be influenced by end user or site visitor.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting relates to the application trust level, which is a ASP.NET security feature.

Make sure you are hosting your instance of Kentico in a [full trust](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyts434y.aspx) environment.
As of Kentico 8.1, only full trust is supported - you can check the hosting requirements [here](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/installation/server-and-hosting-requirements#Serverandhostingrequirements-Hostingrequirements).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like
Select * from (
Select * From CB_Gallery, CB_Products
WHERE 
x= xId AND 
y= 'Y' AND z= 'Y' AND 
) A (##WHERE##) 
ORDER BY z ASC

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that some of the database values has apostrophe in it and when they are executed Kentico is stopping its execution to avoid any SQL injection attacks.

The best way to access values where you expect them to have apostrophe is to use SQL injection safe syntax.

```
{%SQLEscape(QueryString.cs)%} {%SQLEscape(QueryString.csnme.cs)%}
```

You may read about how to write SQL injection safe macro syntax here

http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/security-avoiding-sql-injection-(sqli)